# returning data after post with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some trouble returning data into my ajax Post request.

my function looks like this:

```
 var frm = $('#masterForm');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {           
        $.ajax({               
            type: POST,               
               contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
               dataType: 'json',
               url: $(this).attr("action"),                   
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {                  
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Some Error Occurred! ");
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

and my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FieldQueryResult(QueryInput input)
    {
        var model = new FieldQueryResultView();

           //post some stuff to db, then populate model with other stuff

 return Json(new
        {
            model = model
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The code successfully steps through the FieldQueryResult action but then just loads a page with the result of the model as unformatted text. It never hits my 'success' alert.  How can I get I get the data back to my ajax function?

Comment: sounds like your js isn't running. that or the form doesn't exist when it does run.

Comment: when I put an alert just after  frm.submit(function (ev) {     alert('hello'), that does pop up, so it is entering the submit function

Comment: that doesn't seem possible. if that happens, then the result should be either success or error alert. Unless there's a typo or syntax error i'm not seeing.

Comment: There it is, typo. `type: POST,   `

Comment: what do i change it to?

Comment: @Jynn a string.

Comment: gaetanoM I didn't downvote you, I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143327/discussion-between-jynn-and-kevin-b).

Comment: remove , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, it is a post request

Comment: ah true, actually when I deleted contenttype and datatype from the function I get a succesful return. thanks